# is there a plug-in that exports multiple objects with they original locations from blender to UE4?

Tags: export, import

i modeled this big map in blender and imported it to ue4, for some reason unreal didn't read the materials (even though they were just one base color), that's okay i can recolor them in ue4, the big issue is that i have 2 options while importing it to ue4 , either i combine meshes or it imports separately, is there a way i can keep the map as it is from blender to unreal without resembling everything all over again in ue4

i found a plugin called fbx builder that works great with Maya, and im not switching to Maya anytime soon, so if you guys know a plugin like fbx builder for blender, it would be a life saver

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about the internals of UE 4, not about BLender.

Comment: Models will be exported as one if they are part of one object which consists of many meshes in Blender. See how to join objects - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/how-do-i-make-multiple-blender-objects-into-one

Comment: Why doesn't the regular Blender FBX exporter work for you? Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures about the materals