# Combine/Merge Imported Meshes into one

Tags: mesh, objects, import

Attached you see a picture of my model, which I imported from SolidWorks. on the right i have added a red line, all these i want to merge into one.
[image: Combine Imported Mesh]
if i only press Strg+J, it is only grouped. i really want to join it so i have only one closed mesh.

Comment: To join objects press Ctrl+J. They will become joined into one object consisting of all those meshes you had selected. If you have any particular object you want to stay with its options (its name, or its modifiers list) make it active before joining. See  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/how-do-i-make-multiple-blender-objects-into-one

Comment: ah yes funny, now i selected everything with A and i joined... now i only have 1 mesh on the side. so it worked. thank you