# Is there a way to move multiple objects together?

Tags: animation, transforms

I was wondering if there were a way to make it so multiple objects would act almost like one. I have created a character that is basically a lot of flat objects on top of each other to give a 2D impression but I don't want to have to move each individual item every single time the character moves. Would it be possible to just have them all move together? So if I moved one 2 units over, the rest would as well?

Comment: you can either [group objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105/is-it-possible-to-group-several-objects-and-then-manipulate-them-scale-rotate) or [join their meshes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/how-do-i-make-multiple-blender-objects-into-one)

Answer (score 5):

why not parent them <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (keep offset) under an "Empty" (to use it as a control object) which will be also nested under the main object that you want to inherit the movement from ?

Another method would be to use constraints (like copy location) but I wouldn't suggest you to do it for such simple task.

PS : You may also parent them directly to the main object that you want to inherit the movement of course.