# How to combine 2 planes together into 1 object

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I'm new to blender and I'm running into an issue that's keeping me stuck for the past hour or so. I created 2 objects, a plane that I distorted and a circle, and I want to combine them into one object. I tried pressing i to inset, but that didn't work.

Here's what I have right now:
[image: front view of plane & circle]

and here is a side view:
[image: side view of plane & circle, notice they are detached]

This the the goal I'm trying to get (from a tutorial video, where the circle and plane are attached together):
[image: goal I'm trying to achieve: circle & plane attached together]

I'd appreciate any help on what I can do achieve this effect. Thanks so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make multiple Blender objects into one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/how-do-i-make-multiple-blender-objects-into-one)

Comment: Also, [How do I join several objects into one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5871/how-do-i-join-several-objects-into-one)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I looked at these 2 answers, but unfortunately I get an error: "no mesh data to join" when I do control-J

Comment: What does it mean "combine them into one object"? To join objects in Object mode left click an object, then Shift+left click another one (in this case, triangle and circle), then Ctrl+J.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Ah you're right, I got confused with the terms. It looks like the triangle and the circle are technically the same object (a plane), because when I look under my scene collection, I only see one object. I am just trying to put these 2 components (the triangle and circle) together so they move as one piece

Comment: if they are 2 objects and you want to make one, select them both and press Ctrl J, if you want them to be on the same plan, press S Y 0, and if you want to make one unique mesh you'll need to join the vertices